# a string is printed with spaces where there should not be , there should not be spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

there should be no spaces on the output below ? the output should be just like the one that is a whole string.why is this happening and how do i achieve the required results , btw am new to python

```
print   ('this addWeaponCargo ["srifle_DMR_01_DMS_F", 4];')         #     expected print 
print   (add_weapon_to_vehicle,'["',Rahim,'"',",",Quantity,']',';') #   this is output should be like the one at the top , why are there spaces ?
```

Output

```
this addWeaponCargo ["srifle_DMR_01_DMS_F", 4];
this addWeaponCargo [" srifle_DMR_01_DMS_F " , 4 ] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`print` will put in a space between the supplied arguments, so:

```
print('a','b') # prints: a b
```

You could concatenate the parts with the `+` operator, or use a format string:

```
print('{0} ["{1}", {2}];'.format(add_weapon_to_vehicle, Rahim, Quantity))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3's `print` function has a keyword-only parmeter called `sep` which is put in between the arguments it is passed if there is more than one. By default, `sep` is a single space, but you can change it if you want.

It sounds like you want no spaces, so `sep=""`, will set the separator to an empty string. Try:

```
print(add_weapon_to_vehicle, '["',Rahim, '"', ",", Quantity, ']', ';', sep="")
```

hege_hegedus's answer suggesting using string formatting is also a good one, since it simplifies things a lot when you have both variable parts, and constant parts of your string output (for instance, your comma, brackets, and semicolon in the `print` call above are all constant).